# How To access Opportunity object over customer Portal

Tags: customer-portal

I am designing a customer Portal , having credentials as contact information. I want to access opportunity object over the customer Portal . but I am unable to get access to Opportunity Object.I am using my own Vf pages and custom controller.I am facing the Problem , Iam unable to give assessibility to cutomer Portal user Profile for opportunity object.

Comment: You should go with Partner portal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Customer Community users don't have permission to view Opportunities because their license doesn't allow it. 
The only way around this is to create a mirror object with Opportunities using a trigger to keep the object in sync. You can then display your custom mirror object records to your Customer Community Users. Otherwise, you'll need to purchase Partner Community Licenses.